# how can i create a stop button in android studio for a audio player

Tags: android, android-studio, audio-player, android-music-player

Imma student in IT college and i got a task to make an music player on android, my "track1" is playing, but the second one not, and i need to do a pause button.
Thanks in advance

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button click1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.track1);
    final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.track2);
    View.OnClickListener elem = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    mp1.start();
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    mp2.start();
                    break;

            }
        }
    };

    click.setOnClickListener(elem);
}
```

}

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work
Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

as you start mp2 call pause or stop on mp1 and as you start mp1 call pause or stop on mp2.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#pause()

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#stop()

Comment: If you call `stop()` on a track, make sure to call `prepare()` before you call it next time.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#prepare()

Comment: thanks a lot bruh